enforce strictfp behavior in a Java program run
Is there a way to tell the Java VM to enforce the strictfp behavior across all float point operations regardless of whether the code used the strictfp modifier or not?
I have looked for -X option that would do the trick in Oracle's SE Jdk (I restricted to only use 1.8) but there is such an option.
Is there perhaps a VM for MacOS that in compliant with 1.8 and that only implements strictfp behavior regardless of hardware present?

There is not a lot of hardware that doesn't do strictfp. Especially since you are running on macOS, I don't think this is going to be a problem. Are there any Apple device that doesn't do strictfp?

Your question is moot, as strictfp is a noop. It does nothing, and hasn't for quite a long time. I believe the JVM specs are in fact officially now stating does: It has no effect whatsoever. All fp ops are already strict, simply because all commonly used CPUs in the past decade do that out of the box.

I researched this a long time ago for a different Q&A.  What I found was:

If you could change to using the Oracle JRockit JVM, it has a JVM option to enable strictfp semantics globally: -XstrictFP

According to the 2nd reference, there is a -XX:-UseStrictFP option on some Hotspot JVMs.  However:

It has the reverse effect to what you want; i.e. it disables all strictfp semantics.
It is only available in a "debug version of the VM".
It will have been removed in Java 17 ... along with all other support for strictfp.

I was able to confirm the first two points by looking at the OpenJDK Java 8 source code1.


In summary, there is probably nothing that will help you in a regular Hotspot JVM.
References:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/jrdocs/refman/optionX.html
http://stas-blogspot.blogspot.com.au/2011/07/most-complete-list-of-xx-options-for.html


1 - While looking, I noticed that the JIT compiler for intel platforms does appear to pay some attention to strictfp.  So @rzwitserloot's comment about strictfp being irrelevant on modern hardware might not be correct.  However, I don't have the knowledge or patience to research this properly.
